# Design strategy advice for defining machine system functionality

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, project-planning

This question relates to project design.  The project takes an electrical system and defines it function programatically.  Now that I'm knee-deep in defining the system, I'm incorporating a significant amount of interaction which causes the system to configure itself appropriately.  Example: the system opens and closes electrical contactors when certain events occur.  Because this system is on an airplane, it relies on air/ground logic and thus incorporates two different behaviors depending on where it is.

I give all of this explanation to demonstrate the level of complexity that this application contains.  As I have continued in my design, I have employed the use of if/else constructs as a means of extrapolating the proper configurations in this electrical system.  However, the deeper I get into the coding, the more if/else constructs are required.  I feel that I have reached a point where  I am inefficiently programing this system.

For those who tackled projects like this before, I ask: Am I treading a well-known path (when it comes to defining EVERY possible scenario that could occur) and I should continue to persevere... or can I employ some other strategies to accomplish the task of defining a real-world system's behavior.

At this point, I have little to no experience using delegates, but I wonder if I could utilize some observers or other "cocoa-ey" goodness for checking scenarios in lieu of endless if/else blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to model a real world system, I would suggest creating a concrete object oriented design that well defines the is-a and a has-a relationships and apply good old fashioned object oriented design and apply it into breaking the real world system into a functional decomposition.

I would suggest you look into defining protocols that handle the generic case, and using them on specific cases.

For example, you can have many types of events adhering to an ElectricalEvent protocol and depending on the type you can better decide how an ElectricalContactor discriminates on a GeneralElectricEvent versus a SpecializedElectricEvent using the isKindOfClass selector.

Answer (score 0):

If you can define all the states in advance, you're best of implementing this as a [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). This allows you to define the state-dependent logic clearly in one central place.

There are some implementations that you could look into:

- [SCM](http://smc.sourceforge.net/) allows you to generate state machine code for Objective-C
- OFC implements them as [DFSM](http://code.google.com/p/ofc/wiki/DFSM)

Of course you can also roll your own customized implementation if that suits you better.